# How to create a JQuery UI Dialog to display a HTML code snippet?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog, code-snippets

Typically, the text to display for a JQuery Dialog is put in a hidden `div`, and then called with `$("#cs0").dialog();`.

However, if the text to display is HTML code, such as:

```
  <div id="cs0">
    <a href="http://www.mysite.com/">
      <img border="0" alt="MySite" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/buttons/mybutton.jpg" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

The dialog does not display it literally. How to have the dialog display the `div` content, explicitly, rather than its execution?

See: http://jsfiddle.net/DqgGH/2/

**P.S.**

I tried:

```
$("<div><a href="http://www.mysite.com/"><img border="0" alt="Convert-Kit" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/buttons/mybutton.jpg" /></a></div>").dialog();
```

but it does not work !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to output it as raw HTML is to set the contents of the div using `text()`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="il0">MyButton</div>

<div id="cs0"></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('#cs0').hide();

$('#il0').click(function() {
    $('#cs0').text('<a href="http://www.mysite.com/"><img border="0" alt="MySite" src="http://www.mysite.com/images/buttons/mybutton.jpg" /></a>').dialog();
});
```